# Should questions be closed just because they cover too many subtopics?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I stumbled on this question the other day:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403463/help-picking-a-decent-application-framework-for-upcoming-java-web-project/6403835#6403835

and gave what I thought was a reasonably precise answer on it. I was hoping to see more responses or some comments, but then the question was closed as "Not Constructive." I agree that perhaps it was asking a few too many things at once, but I'm wondering if that's really the intent behind "Not Constructive." Am I reading the explanatory text too literally? Is there a better way of handling questions like that?

Comment: Sure is a reheheheally specific question the got there. Almost like a green Honda Civic.

Comment: Umm...this isn't intended to be a joke. I've been on SO for a while but didn't closely follow the discussion surrounding the "Not Constructive" close reason so I'm just trying to understand it. I'm not saying the referenced question is the best question ever.

Comment: Welcome to meta!  Jokes are for fun; but we take your question seriously.  Also downvotes are different; they just represent disagreement with your point-of-view.

Comment: @Rick. I see. Alright, I'll play along.

Comment: Wasn't joking, but they sure sound extremely specific about what they want people to help them pick things out for.

Answer (score 10):

The asker's own comment is the clincher:

> I thought my 605 word posting had
>   enough specifics of what I'm looking
>   for. **I'd like to hear someones
>   subjective opinions** if possible

which fits perfectly with the description of "Not Constructive":

> This question is not a good fit to our
>   Q&A format. We expect answers to
>   generally involve facts, references,
>   or specific expertise; this question
>   will likely **solicit opinion**, debate,
>   arguments, polling, or extended
>   discussion.

---

in response to comment:

I think closing it was a good call, but there's room to debate which reason is the best fit.

- The "extended discussion" part of "Not constructive" could also come into play: an answer covering all those points would be like a Masters thesis.
- "Too localized" could work due to the extremely specific details.
- "Not a real question" sounds wrong since it's clearly a real question, however the description fits:

  - "overly broad"
  - "...cannot reasonably be answered..."
  - "rhetorical" could even fit, since no one can answer his real question, which is "*will I be happy with this framework?*". The only way to know is for him to try it out and experiment with it for a while. When I had to pick a framework, I did some research to narrow the list, and then tried making real (though somewhat simple) applications with each of my top four candidates. That's really the only sensible way to make this kind of decision that you're going to be stuck with for years to come.

Overall I think "Not Constructive" sums up all the different issues fairly well.

Comment: Fair enough, but even still, the quote is out of context. It was only in response to a complaint that the question was subjective, which it wasn't really. The question as I read it was "how can these goals be achieved using Spring, and if they can't, what Java framework can?" That's perhaps too broad for one question, but it's not really subjective. Relatedly, my point in posting here was not to debate the merits of that post but to ask the purpose of the "Not Constructive" reason and why it applied here. Still, I see what you're getting at. "extended discussion" could certainly apply.